# Flutter: Why are the methods inside this function not accessing the database variable?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, sqflite

I have a file named `database_services.dart`. This file have a class with various methods. The first method open the database and store the reference, while the other methods make inclusions, updates and deletes on this database. The problem is that the other methods are unable to see the database created by the first method. What am I missing?

Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'counter.dart';

class DatabaseServices {
  initDatabase() async {
    // Open the database and store the reference.
    final Future<Database> database = openDatabase(
      // Set the path to the database.
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'counter_database.db'),
      // When the database is first created, create a table to store counters;
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        // Run the CREATE TABLE statement on the database.
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE counters(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER)",
        );
      },
      // Set the version. This executes the onCreate function and provides a
      // path to perform database upgrades and downgrades.
      version: 1,
    );
  }

    // Define a function that inserts counters into the database.
    Future<void> insertCounter(Counter counter) async {
      // Get a reference to the database.
      final Database db = await database;
      // Insert the Counter into the correct table. Here, if a counter is inserted twice,
      // it replace any previous data.
      await db.insert(
        'counters',
        counter.toMap(),
        conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
      );
    }
}
    // A method that retrieves all the counters from the counters table.
    Future<List<Counter>> counters() async {
      // Get a reference to the database.
      final Database db = await database;
      // Query the table for all the Counters.
      final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('counters');
      // Counvert the List<Map<String, dynamic>> into a List<Counter>
      return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
        return Counter(
          id: maps[i]['id'],
          name: maps[i]['name'],
          value: maps[i]['value'],
        );
      });
    }

    // Method to update a Counter in the database
    Future<void> updateCounter(Counter counter) async {
      final db = await database;
      await db.update(
        'counters',
        counter.toMap(),
        where: "id = ?",
        whereArgs: [counter.id],
      );
    }

    //Delete a Counter from the database
    Future<void> deleteCounter(int id) async {
      final db = await database;
      await db.delete(
        'counters',
        where: "id = ?",
        whereArgs: [id],
      );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `database` variable is only stored in the `initDatabase` method instead of on the `DatabaseServices` class, which means that it will only be accessible from the `initDatabase` method.

The code sample below shows how you could store the `database` as a property on the `DatabaseServices` class, which would allow it to be used by all the methods inside that class.

```dart
class DatabaseServices {
  Future<Database> _db;

  Future<void> initDatabase() async {
    // Open the database and store the reference.
    _db = openDatabase(
      // Set the path to the database.
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'counter_database.db'),
      // When the database is first created, create a table to store counters;
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        // Run the CREATE TABLE statement on the database.
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE counters(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER)",
        );
      },
      // Set the version. This executes the onCreate function and provides a
      // path to perform database upgrades and downgrades.
      version: 1,
    );
  }

  // Define a function that inserts counters into the database.
  Future<void> insertCounter(Counter counter) async {
    // Get a reference to the database.
    final db = await _db;
    // Insert the Counter into the correct table. Here, if a counter is inserted twice,
    // it replace any previous data.
    await db.insert(
      'counters',
      counter.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
    );
  }

  // A method that retrieves all the counters from the counters table.
  Future<List<Counter>> counters() async {
    // Get a reference to the database.
    final db = await _db;
    // Query the table for all the Counters.
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('counters');
    // Counvert the List<Map<String, dynamic>> into a List<Counter>
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Counter(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        name: maps[i]['name'],
        value: maps[i]['value'],
      );
    });
  }

  // Method to update a Counter in the database
  Future<void> updateCounter(Counter counter) async {
    final db = await _db;
    await db.update(
      'counters',
      counter.toMap(),
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [counter.id],
    );
  }

  //Delete a Counter from the database
  Future<void> deleteCounter(int id) async {
    final db = await _db;
    await db.delete(
      'counters',
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }
}
```

You can find more information about opening a database [here](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_db.md).